# MySQL does not work on localhost without Local Area Connection

Tags: mysql, firewall, wampserver

I use WampServer (Apache, PHP, MySQL) and **have no problems when some kind of network adapter(wireless or lan) is connected** (i.e. Local Area Connection has status connected) **even if i am not connected to the internet** (for example when i am connected to the router but that is not connected to the internet).

When there is no network connection, I get a php error like MySQL could not connect to 127.0.0.1 on port 3306.

Interestingly, `telnet 127.0.0.1 3306` says that it could not connect to the port, even when the server and MySQL are running fine (i.e. when some kind of local area connection is connected).

So I turned off all kinds of firewall (antivirus and Windows) but still no difference in anything. And that is why this issue is quite puzzling.

Things I have already tried (will update this list along the way):

- The skip-networking directive in my.ini.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your MySQL server and client configuration to connect to one another using a named pipe instead of a TCP/IP loopback connection. That way, the current state of the network connection should have less impact.

To do so, start the server with [`--enable-named-pipe`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_enable-named-pipe) or the corresponding config file setting, and execute the client with [`--pipe`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connecting.html#option_general_pipe) or [`--protocol=PIPE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connecting.html#option_general_protocol). Similar configurations should be available for your PHP connector as well. It may depend on which library you use there, and whether or not it will take the mentioned configuration settings from the `my.ini` file (settings without leading `--` there).